# Add a new taskbar (panel) to second monitor in Linux Mint 18.1 (Serena)

Tags: linux-mint, multi-monitor, panel, mate-panel

I'm using Linux Mint 18.1 (Serena) and I would like to add a new taskbar/panel, to use and track the windows in the second monitor.
All of the solutions I have read say to

- Right click the existing panel
- Click on `Add New Panel`.
- Right click the new panel
- Click `Properties`, then unmark `Expand`.
- Drag the panel to the second monitor.

This last step is the problem for me, since Mint won't let me drag the panel outside of the bounds of the first monitor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To the downvoter: I read all of the first page of Google before asking, and also [I can answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It's still baffling that people can downvote without explaining themselves. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by going to `Preferences > Displays` and reconfiguring the displays/monitors. My left display was bleeding a bit into the right monitor, which was an older problem that didn't bother me, and that must have been an issue (invalid state or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who wants to do this but cant drag the panel, you can just add panel 4 times and it will add the 4th panel to the other screen. then delete the 3 new panels on your main screen.